# Azure Tables - Generic error message

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I get the following error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidInput</code>
  <message xml:lang="sv-SE">One of the request inputs is not valid.</message>
</error>
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
at MvcWebRole1.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\jgauffin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Azure.OneTrueError\MvcWebRole1\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 20
```

which doesn't really say anything. How can I get a more detailed error?

I'm using the latest storage nuget package and is trying to debug locally (using the emulator).

Comment: you're probably trying to save unsupported data type..  more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx

Comment: It's why I try to use `SetLink` like this: `ctx.SetLink(organization, "CreatedBy", account);`